# KDE - Controlling the Cooperation of Multiple Task Managers

Tags: multiple-monitors, kde, launcher, workspaces, plasma-5

When you have multiple **Icons-Only Task Managers**, how do you control the behavior as it pertains to their cooperation with each other? The ability to do this, is crucial to my desired workflow.

In Kubuntu (KDE), I have placed a panel onto each of 3 monitors, and I've added an **Icons-Only Task Manager** widget onto each of those 3 panels/monitors. Additionally, I pin all my application launchers to each of these panels (despite the fact that these running applications will ultimately span multiple **monitors** and **workspaces**). The purpose of this redundancy, is so that no matter which monitor or workspace my mouse cursor is currently on, I'm one **proxmal** click away for bringing focus to the application I want to focus (no matter what monitor or workspace that application it is on).

Now, I'm trying to control the general behavior of click-launching and click-task-switching as described below.

**Freshly Launched Applications:**

When I freshly launch an application from a particular monitor, I want that application to be placed onto the vary **monitor** and **workspace** from which I clicked that launcher.

**Update:** To get applications launching to the same screen of the clicked-launcher, you have to do two things:

**1)** System Settings > Window Management > Window Behavior > Advanced
    (tab) > Placement > Select "Under Mouse":

[image]

**2)** System Settings > Window Management > Window Behavior > Focus (tab) > Check "Active screen follows mouse":

[image]

**Already Launched Applications:**

If I click on an application-launcher that's already running, I want KDE to do two things:

1. Automatically switch to the **workspace** that contains that
   running application.
2. Bring that application's window above all other windows, onto the
   vary monitor and workspace from which that running-application was originally
   launched.

I hope I do not have to micro-manage this general behavior by configuring each application window separately. Where can I control this general behavior for all applications, on all monitors, and all workspaces?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/ezrvox/kde_controlling_the_cooperation_of_multiple_task/